# Mysql Find command has become very slow

Tags: mysql, performance

Each of my web requests involved couple of 'select' queries. Table in question recently went from 75,000 rows to ~90,000 and the select command slowed from taking ~100ms to ~1.2s

What is the best way to find the reason of sudden performance drop? I imagine that key can not be stored in memory and this is causing the drop. How to check for that?

Please advise.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like MySQL is shifting an internal table from memory to disk. This is a classic "tipping-point" with MySQL where performance drops off a cliff once something reaches a certain size. This is especially so when you realize that the default MySQL configuration is extremely conservative (even the so-called "huge" config) and several server settings can be increased by at least an order of magnitude.

The first avenue of exploration is to use `EXPLAIN` on your query and look for indications it is putting temporary table information on disk. More information is available in the MySQL docs [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/using-explain.html) and [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/Data_size.html)

Comment: this is what I got -> | id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------+-----------------------
|  1 | SIMPLE      | fb_welcome_tabs | ref  | index_fb_welcome_tabs_on_fb_sig_page_id,index_fb_welcome_tabs_on_fb_sig_app_id | index_fb_welcome_tabs_on_fb_sig_page_id | 53      | const |    1 | Using where |

Comment: Have a look in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimizing-the-server.html particularly sections 1, 2 and 4. It sounds like you need to raise the size of the key buffer.

Answer (score 1):

EXPLAIN PLAN on the query.  Look for a TABLE SCAN.

If you find one, add sufficient indexes to eliminate the problem.